# Solving a second order PDE with no BC

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve `D[y[x,t],t]-y[x,t]-D[y[x,t],{x,2}]==0`. Using `DSolve[D[y[x,t],t]-y[x,t]-D[y[x,t],{x,2}]==0,y[x,t],{x,t}]` does not seem to work (i get the input as the output, so nothing changes). I know the solution of this "by hand", but i want to have also a solution via Mathematica.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

V 12.1 can't solve this diffusion PDE with extra dependent variable in rhs.

$$
{\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}y \left( x,t \right) ={\frac {\partial 
^{2}}{\partial {x}^{2}}}y \left( x,t \right) +y \left( x,t \right) 
$$

Maple 2020 can solve it. Verified it in Mathematica to be valid

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t] == D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] + y[x, t];
try = C[3]*Exp[(1+C[4]) t] C[1] Exp[Sqrt[C[4]] x]+C[3] Exp[(1 + C[4]) t] C[2] 1/Exp[Sqrt[C[4]] x];
```

$$
y(x,t)=c_1 c_3 e^{(1+c_4) t+\sqrt{c_4} x}+c_2 c_3 e^{(1+c_4) t-\sqrt{c_4} x}
$$

```
sol = y -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@try  ]
pde /. sol // Simplify
(* True *)
```

Here is Maple code

```
restart;
pde:=diff(y(x,t),t)=diff(y(x,t),x$2)+y(x,t);
sol:=pdsolve(pde,y(x,t),explicit)
```

$$
y \left( x,t \right) ={\it \_C3}\,{{\rm e}^{t{\it \_c}_{{1}}}}{{\rm e}
^{t}}{\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{\sqrt {{\it \_c}_{{1}}}x}}+{{\it \_C3}\,{
{\rm e}^{t{\it \_c}_{{1}}}}{{\rm e}^{t}}{\it \_C2} \left( {{\rm e}^{
\sqrt {{\it \_c}_{{1}}}x}} \right) ^{-1}}
$$

Hopefully next version of `DSolve` will be able to solve this.

Comment: Could one not linearize it to an ODE and solve it with Mathematica? I suppose that does require prior knowledge that it would be possible...

Answer (score 3):

Maple's solution is just the multiplication separation of variables solution and is in no way the general solution.  Although Mathematica does not solve the equation with that solution directly, we can use separation of variables with Mathematica to get there.

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t] == D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] + y[x, t]

y[x_, t_] = X[x] T[t]

pde/y[x, t] // Expand
(*T'[t]/T[t] == X''[x]/X[x] + 1)
```

The LHS is a function of `T` only while the RHS is a function of `x` only, so each side must be equal to a constant.  Use the separation constant a

```
DSolve[pde[[1]] == a, T[t], t] // Flatten
(*{T[t] -> C[1] E^(a t)}*)

T[t_] = T[t] /. % /. C[1] -> 1

DSolve[pde[[2]] == a, X[x], x] // Flatten
(*{X[x] -> C[1] E^(Sqrt[a - 1] x) + C[2] E^(-Sqrt[a - 1] x)}*)

X[x_] = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}

y[x, t]
(*E^(a t) (c1 E^(Sqrt[a - 1] x) + c2 E^(-Sqrt[a - 1] x))*)
```

which is the same answer as Maple's without the extraneous constants.  Note I set `C[1]` to 1 in the `t` equation because it will just be joined with the constants in the `x` equation.

If you like Trig instead of exponentials, we could say

```
y[x, t][[1]] ExpToTrig[y[x, t][[2]]] // Collect[#, {Sinh[Sqrt[a - 1] x], Cosh[Sqrt[a - 1] x]}] & // Simplify
(*E^(a t) ((c1 - c2) Sinh[Sqrt[a - 1] x] + (c1 + c2) Cosh[ Sqrt[a - 1] x])*)

y[x_, t_] = % /. {c1 - c2 -> c1, c1 + c2 -> c2}
(*E^(a t) (c1 Sinh[Sqrt[a - 1] x] + c2 Cosh[Sqrt[a - 1] x])*)
```

Check

```
pde // Simplify
(*True*)
```

I do like Maple's pdsolve command with its HINT options specifying separation of variables as well as other choices, but as far as general solutions to pde's goes, neither program can really do the job for most pde's.  The separation of variables solution is but one small subset of the general solution of a pde without boundary conditions which may be why Mathematica does not furnish that specific solution.